# Stopping power diminishing despite good-looking brake pads?

Tags: brakes

The stopping power of my car has diminished to the point where I felt I needed to replace the front brake pads. It has also been a couple of years since I last replaced them. When I took the old pads off to replace them, I noticed the old pads looked rather good, nowhere near the danger zone. In fact, they looked really good.

Besides checking the brake fluid levels, how else can I diagnose this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Does it brake well if you press the brake pedal hard? Not suddenly, but slowly excerting more force with your feet.

Comment: @Martin I'd say that when I really need to stop is when I notice the diminished stopping power. During normal braking, the pads feel fine. It was after a few hard stops when I decided to order some new pads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you did the work yourself, did you have the rotors turned or use new rotors? And if you did, did you bed the brake pads to the rotors? Both of these things are rather important when changing brake pads. If you don't, the pads won't work up to their potential.

Also, what type of brake pads are you using? Ceramic pads tend to work much better than organic, semi-metallic, or metallic.

When was the last time you flushed the brake fluid? Brake fluid should be changed out every two years. It absorbs water, which lowers the boiling point, which can cause issues when under high stress conditions.

You need to check the rubber portions of the brake lines to ensure there's no bulges or that it doesn't bulge under pressure. Have someone step on the brake pedal and then go around and check to see if any of the lines might be causing you issues.

I'm assuming whatever vehicle you are driving has power brakes. If it is actuated via vacuum assist, check to ensure there's no leaks at the canister or the line going from it to the intake manifold where it draws vacuum.

Comment: Also consider checking that the calipers/slide pins move freely